# Rcmdr BiodiversityR GUI Crash on Mac OSX

Tags: r, macos, x11, rgui, r-commander

**Running Fully updated:**
MACOSX 10.10.4 , R 3.2.1 World Famous Astronaut , R commander 2.1.7 , X11 2.7.7, Java 8, Biodiversity R 2.5.2

When i run script/data/commands that I know should work in Biodiversity R, I can run analysis, but when i try to create a plot the Quartz window crashes, beachball appears, and I can only escape by force quit.

Two issues may or may not contribute to quartz crashing which i cannot resolve;
When i first run R I randomly get this warning. By randomly I mean at anytime when working in r, not necessarily after I have run a command:

> WARNING: Method convertPointFromBase: in class NSView is deprecated on 10.7 and later. It should not be used in new applications.

When I run `BiodiversityR`, it launches fine, but I get this message:

> Attaching package: 'Rcmdr'
>   The following objects are masked from 'package:tcltk':
>       tclvalue, tkfocus

I have uninstalled and reinstalled X11. I can only find solutions so far that are relevant for older versions, so I am unsure of where my error is occurring. In my search a lot of people seem to be experiencing these errors and issues. Thank you to anyone who can help.